# Nodejs - tips for creating multiple endpoints

Tags: node.js, express, endpoint

I have a nodejs/express server being used by both Web application and Mobile application, but for now they use the same end points. But I want to divide my api into 2 one of which is for mobile and obviously the other is for web. The requests are going to be "exactly" the same. What comes to my mind as a solution is duplicating all the request where paths for newly created ones are different(so that in the mobile app, these request can be used). But this solution does not seem right, as it may mean making big changes on the client side. Is there an elegant and also favourably easier solution? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
router.get('api/snow/manuel',
function (req, res, next) {
    const snowProjection = {_id: 0};
    snowThick.find({}, snowProjection)
        .toArray(function (err, data) {     
            if (err) return next(new APIError.ServerError("An error occured" + " " + err));
            return res.send(data);
        })
});
```

Here is an sample get request in my server.

Comment: Is the request response structure exactly the same for mobile and web?

Comment: If its the same api that you use and no change in functionality, then just having different endpoints is a bad idea.

Comment: @yaswanth Yes, they are exactly the same for mobile and web.

Comment: @eduPeeth the functionality is the same but security system will differ, so two endpoints are required.

Comment: One way is to have the client pass a header saying whether it's web or mobile and deal with the difference in functionality on server accordingly

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only change server or mobile application(still not preferable). But thanks!

Comment: If its about the security, why do you want to handle it at requests level. You can use middle ware and probably put some logic in there.